# Redirecting website causes flickering

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, uri

I have to redirect to a website when Android app launches. It will work fine but it's flickering when app launches. The following code I have tried with two different methods: method 1 using `Webview`; method 2 using `URI` and `Intent`.

```
// method 1
this.webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

// method 2
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please give me the solution.

Regards
Venkatesan

Comment: Why are you using both together? If you are loading in the webview you do not need the intent

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just tried these two different ways i.e commenting the first approach and tried with webview its still flickering. if I commenting the second approach and tried with intent its still flickering.

Comment: Flickering make sense since it takes time to load. If speed is important, you can use `Chrome custom tabs`. However, you may want to load a splash screen until the webview loads, to avoid the flickering.

Comment: Well you need only one or the other. Doing both will make things worse. Where is this code? POst a larger snippet

Comment: Thanks for all. I go with the splash screen until webview loads..